# How to count a letter that appears right after an especific letter in a COLUMN?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the column B**A**BCB**A**BC**A**B**AA**CBC**A**BB**A**CC**A**B**A**BC**A**C**A**BCBB**A**C**AA**CBBB**A**BBB**A**C**A**CB**A**.
How many times each letter appears after letter A?
In this example:

A = 2

B = 8

C = 7

I tried using COUNT, SUM, but nothing yet...

It may help:

```
INSERT INTO `letras` (`id`, `letra`) VALUES
(1, 'B'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'B'),
(4, 'C'),
(5, 'B'),
(6, 'A'),
(7, 'B'),
(8, 'C'),
(9, 'A'),
(10, 'B'),
(11, 'A'),
(12, 'A'),
(13, 'C'),
(14, 'B'),
(15, 'C'),
(16, 'A'),
(17, 'B'),
(18, 'B'),
(19, 'A'),
(20, 'C'),
(21, 'C'),
(22, 'A'),
(23, 'B'),
(24, 'A'),
(25, 'B'),
(26, 'C'),
(27, 'A'),
(28, 'C'),
(29, 'A'),
(30, 'B'),
(31, 'C'),
(32, 'B'),
(33, 'B'),
(34, 'A'),
(35, 'C'),
(36, 'A'),
(37, 'A'),
(38, 'C'),
(39, 'B'),
(40, 'B'),
(41, 'B'),
(42, 'A'),
(43, 'B'),
(44, 'B'),
(45, 'B'),
(46, 'A'),
(47, 'C'),
(48, 'A'),
(49, 'C'),
(50, 'B'),
(51, 'A');
```

Comment: This isn't a row!?!? (Which is a good thing)

Comment: Column I meant... Thank you.

Comment: An edit button is provided!

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, LEAD(letra) OVER (ORDER BY id) nextletter
              FROM letras )
SELECT nextletter, COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE letra = 'A'
GROUP BY nextletter;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39ba01b95f0e7ac14475b4c20d43a06f)

Comment: Great! Thank you! One more question: if I had to count the before letter? In This case: A=2, B=9, C=7 Edited:  by using ORDER BY -id

Comment: @ClaudioCaetano: you can use lag function then

Comment: First time I use LEAD and LAG MySql functions. Thank you all about what i´ve learned!!

Comment: @ClaudioCaetano Either use LAG() like Pygirl says or use `ORDER BY id DESC`. *Edited: by using ORDER BY -id* - this is wrong because does not allow to use an index.